# coverage cannot find modules in my project

Tags: python, python-3.x, coverage.py

I am trying to use coverage from the terminal (as I am using the community version of pycharm, which doesn't have support for coverage). However, I always get the same error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'` The package structure of my project is very simple: it has 2 packages, src and test, and inside the test package is another package called unit, wherer I keep my unit tests.

This is the code that I have trying to run with coverage.

```
import unittest
from src.interpolacion import interpolacion

class DummyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_nothing(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Please notice how src.interpolacion.interpolacion is not even used and, regardless, it fails with this error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: DummyTest (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: DummyTest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jose.m.ramirez.leon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\jose.m.ramirez.leon\PycharmProjects\dummyPythonProject\test\unit\DummyTest.py", line 2, in <module>
    from src.interpolacion import interpolacion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I am going mad with this. Could anyone please help me regain my sanity?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am running the following command from the terminal:  ```coverage run -m unittest DummyTest.py```

Comment: Seems like you are trying to access `src` module from another folder

Comment: @knosmos yes, exactly, from the ```test/unit``` folder, so, what should I do?

Comment: try something like https://gist.github.com/JungeAlexander/6ce0a5213f3af56d7369